# How to update data from database in a view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2. I am printing currency values from database in a view:

```
<div class="hidden">
@foreach ($currencies as $currency)
    <div class="currency-{{ $currency->id }}">
        <div class="cur-id">{{ $currency->id }}</div>
        <div class="cur-name">{{ $currency->cur_name }}</div>
        <div class="cur-sell">{{ $currency->cur_sell + 0 }}</div>
        <div class="cur-buy">{{ $currency->cur_buy + 0 }}</div>
        <div class="cur-reserve">{{ $currency->cur_reserve + 0 }}</div>
        <div class="cur-short">{{ $currency->cur_short }}</div>
        <div class="cur-wallet">{{ $currency->cur_wallet }}</div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Code above lists all currencies from database with its fields. Question is - how can I update these values without page reload with Ajax? I need to make a GET request with ajax then replace data with actual one.

Comment: Well you have the right idea, so now you have to research how to do it and then try to code it. If you have problems with the code you write, come on back and ask for help with that code. Thats what this site is for. However it is not here to ___write your code for you___

Comment: What triggers the request, and what values do you pass?

Answer (score 0):

## You can try some thing like this

In your ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
url : 'getresult',
method : 'get',
dataType : 'Json',
data : formdata, 
success : function(data){
// console.log(data.length);
$.each(data, function( key, value ) {
for(var i=0; i< data[key].length; i++){
$(".currency").html("");
$(".currency").append(
'<div class="cur-id">'+value[i].id+'</div>');
$(".currency").append(
'<div class="cur-name">'+value[i].name+'</div>');
}
});
}, 
error : function(){
alert('error');
}
});
```